# Why Valac generates these (meaningless?) temp pointers in C code

Tags: c, compilation, compiler-optimization, vala

I began to study Vala, and now I dont understand why in these examples the variable tmp1 is created if it was possible to use tmp0 at once?
[image]
And same with tmp1 tm3 here
[image]

I read the documentation a bit but didn't understand why valac generates these temp pointers.
https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Hacking#Documentation

I really want to understand how the Vala compiler works.Now i  think that it relies heavily on the optimization that will happen in gcc with -O3 and apparently it is included by default. I tried compiling with the-O3 flag and without, and the weight of the binaries was the same.

Comment: Pictures of code are useless. Please post code as text.

Comment: I suspect that the reason for what appears to be extra code is due to the Vala compiler being fairly new and its optimizing logic that is used to determine the C source code emitted is being improved. The goal of Vala is to make using the GNOME libraries easier and safer as compared to the effort required for using them with C. Not sure that having a few extra, unneeded pointer variables is that much of a big deal. Tools of this sort generally produce less than optimal source and their main feature is convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason is to avoid undefined behavior.  In C, the order arguments are evaluated in is undefined.  For example, if you have something like

```
int x = 1;
foo(x++, x++);
```

You could be calling `foo(1, 2)` or `foo(2, 1)`.

In Vala, the order is defined; it will be `foo(1, 2)`.  To do this, Vala sometimes needs to use temporary variables, so the code turns into something like:

```
int x = 1;
int tmp0 = x++;
int tmp1 = x++;
foo(tmp0, tmp1);
```

To keep the code generator simple, the temporary variables are just always generated.

Any C compiler will optimize the temporary variables away easily (you don't need `-O3`, `-O1` is more than enough for this), so there isn't much reason to change valac to eliminate the temporary variables.  The only real downside is that the generated code is a little uglier.